# dynamic programming with serially independent returns

Tags: optimization, returns

[Book](http://books.google.com/books?id=SWFkCIRMNtoC&pg=PA203&dq=%22dynamic%20programming%22%20%22expected%20utility%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bml3VJX-CsX8igKx4YCgBQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22dynamic%20programming%22%20%22expected%20utility%22&f=false) suggests that "asset returns are assumed to be serially independent, so wealth is a single state connecting one period to the next". I understand path dependency is lost in case of serial independence but how do all states at a stage collapse to a single state?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me, would you care to elaborate, please?

Comment: I am unable to understand the statement made in the 2nd paragraph of page 215 of the Book. My understanding is that returns must have a distribution at each stage and so wealth must have a distribution. Hence, there must be a fan like structure connected to another fan like structure. I am struggling to understand the shape of the scenario tree.

Comment: I guess it just says that if returns $(r_k)_{k\geq 0}$ are independent, then the wealth $S_n = S_0 \mathrm e^{\sum_k r_k}$ is a Markov process: distribution of $S_{n+1}$ given $S_n$ is same as distribution of $S_{n+1}$ given the whole history $S_0,\dots,S_n$

Comment: Can you explain that in terms of the shape of the scenario tree in dynamic programming context with stages and states

Comment: Not sure what is the scenario tree - can you give an available reference?